# Komodo Edit and localhost

Tags: localhost, komodoedit

Having Windows7x64, WAMP server and Komodo Edit, I want to open in browser via `localhost` local file c:\wamp\www\site1\index.php with simple phpinfo(); inside. - And yes - I did mapping in Edit - Preferences - Mapped URIs ( `http://localhost/site1` corresponds to "c:\wamp\www\site1" ). - However, in browser I see "file:///C:/wamp/www/site1/index.php". - Does someone here know how to overcome this? - It all works perfectly in PhpStorm, Netbeans, phpDesigner and Codelobster... - But they are all not free and therefore I would like to achieve this in Komodo Edit.

Comment: could you please clarify, what do you try to do? I use Komodo Edit also and may be I can help you. Now it is not very clear. If you want to open index.php via localhost, that is through a web server, then I cannot understand how the Komodo Edit is related to this? You need to configure your web server and open in a browser something like `http://localhost/index.php`

Answer (score 1):

Use a more generic URI mapping:

> `file:///C:/wamp/www/`

maps to:

> `http://localhost/`

Otherwise, use the "Properties and Settings" preference for the `index.php` file:

- Go to the "Edit->Current File Settings" menu
- Customize the "Preview URL" to be

  ```
  http://localhost/site1
  ```

**References**

- [URI Mapping Problem](http://community.activestate.com/forum/uri-mapping-problem)
- [Cannot open PHP file as web page](http://community.activestate.com/forum-topic/cannot-open-php-file-web-page)
- [file:///C:/wamp/www to http://localhost](http://community.activestate.com/node/8679)
- [Komodo Edit Preview files in browser at local host](http://community.activestate.com/node/8933)
- [Previewing using Localhost as the URL](http://community.activestate.com/forum/previewing-using-localhost-url)